# Lightning Web Components with Express.js

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is it possible to use lwc with Express.js (with multiple routing, e.g. /user, /account etc.)?

I am currently working on a api integration with UI. The api integration I will handle with Express and UI I am planning to use LWC. I could not find  a solution which uses of both them.

Sure there is a repo https://lwc-recipes-oss.herokuapp.com/ as an example, normally I can improve this but I could not find a routing config for this app (with multiple routing, e.g. /user, /account etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer, actually it was easy because the Salesforce team already provided the solution.

Under the link https://lwc.dev/guide/install, when you install lwc with npx, it asks "Use custom Express server configuration" and you can say it yes and the Express.js server configuration is already under index.js.